# How to segue back from one view controller to another within a custom UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, segue

I want to segue back from ViewControllerTwo to ViewControllerOne. I created a button that is responsible for doing that, but my problem is that the button is part of custom UIView class that is added to ViewControllerTwo, the button is not a part of the main view of ViewControllerTwo.

So in the custom UIView class I have the method that reacts if the button is clicked...

```
-(void)buttonClicked{
    [SecondViewController performSegueWithIdentifier: "ShowFirstViewController" sender:nil];
 }
```

When I do this I get an error: "performSegueWithIdentifier not a method of class" which makes sense.

So how can I segue between two viewcontrollers where the button responsible for the segue is not actually part of either view controller and is in a different class.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more on your question.  Each `ViewController` class has its own `UIView`, so what do you mean when you say that one of the view controllers has a custom `UIView`?  Do you mean that you have a subclass of `UIView` as the `UIView` that belongs to one of the controllers?  You might want to include your header files, to show us what delegates what, and what protocols they abide by.

Comment: Yea I have subclassed uiview and added it to the the uiview of the controller.

Comment: Right on, looks like you got it to work!  Nice work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have a delegate call back to your `SecondViewController` and implement the `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the delegate callback method in `SecondViewController`.

It goes like this:

Above your custom UIView class interface create a protocol like this

```
@protocol CustomViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)buttonDidTap;
@end
```

Then create a property in your interface

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CustomViewDelegate> delegate;
```

In your custom UIView *.m add this

```
-(void)buttonClicked{
    [self.delegate buttonDidTap];
 }
```

Conform the protocol to your `SecondViewController` like this

```
@interface SecondViewController: UIViewController <CustomViewDelegate>
```

set the delegate in your `viewDidLoadMethod` like this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.yourCustomView.delegate = self;
}
```

implement this method inside the view controller .m file

```
- (void)buttonDidTap{
[self.performSegueWithIdentifier: "ShowFirstViewController" sender:self];
}
```

I'm more of a swift guy i think this should work fine.

Comment: Can you show an example as I am a bit confused of what code to write

Comment: I edited my answer here just now you can go through it.

Comment: Ok thnak you. Just one problem. I cannot declare the property: "delegate". I get a warning saying "Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property "delegate" it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention"

Comment: use this instead of weak property:@property (__unsafe_unretained) id <CustomViewDelegate> delegate;

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 9.3, Xcode 7.3, ARC enabled**

This is what I'd do to troubleshoot:

**Step 1:** Make sure that you have a proper storyboard identifier for the *view controllers* you wish to segue between.  The views simply attach to the view controllers, custom or not.

To do this, go to "*.storyboard" show the Utilities (right pane) and navigate to the Identity Inspector.  Make sure you have "ShowFirstViewController" entered in the Storyboard ID field.

[image]